# giving an argument &str and get parameter char *str[]

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void fn(char *string[]) {  
    printf("string[0] - %p %s\n", string[0], string[0]);
    printf("string[1] - %p %s\n", string[1], string[1]);
    printf("string[2] - %p %s\n", string[2], string[2]);
    printf("string[3] - %p %s\n", string[3], string[3]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char *str1 = "AAAAA";
   char *str2 = "XXXXX";
   char *str3 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str1) + 1);
   strcpy(str3, "BBBBB"); 
   char *str4 = "CCCCC"; 

   fn(&str3);

   return 0;
}

output :
string[0] - 0x561c977682a0 BBBBB
string[1] - 0x561c96884050 AAAAA
string[2] - 0x561c96884056 XXXXX
string[3] - 0x561c9688405c CCCCC
```

this is the code and the result. I set an argument as `&str3` and parameter of function `fn` as `*string[]`. I know `malloc` makes `str3` placed in a dynamic area and the others (`str1`, `str2` and `str4`) placed in the memory in a row (`str1<str2<str4`). but how can the result be like this even though I only called `str3`? I don't exactly know the relation between `&str3` and `char* string[]`.

Comment: You are playing with undefined behavior here. `string[1..3]` do not exist.

Comment: The pointer variables happen to be right next to each other in the stack frame.

Comment: @Barmar if I put &str4 as an argument then the String result[0~3] is C, A, X, B at fn. I guess string[0] is what the argument is calling from Main. but I dont still get the order of  ,array of pointer, "string" at this code.

Comment: The compiler might be reordering the other variables. As the first comment said, this is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: Use godbolt.org to see how each version is being compiled.

Comment: _the others (str1, str2 and str4) placed in the memory in a row (str1<str2<str4)._ **No** they can be placed _anywhere_ and in any order and no guarantee that they are even contiguous.